# How to add custom control in fabric.js 3.6.2?

Tags: javascript, web, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to add custom control box like close button near selection box. How can I do that in fabric.js version 3.6.2. I only find ways do that in fabric.js version 4 but I don't know how to include it in my front-end only website.